# Trouble getting count of points inside polygon with PostGIS

Tags: gis, postgis, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to find points from one table that fall within polygons from another table. Both tables have a geom column, both are using SRID 4326 which I confirmed using `SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM poursafe.ca_licenses LIMIT 1;`

I didn't create the polygon table with an SRID which should have been 2229. So, I ran this to convert it to 4326 which may be part of the problem?

```
  ALTER TABLE public.ca_la_la_areas_neighborhoods ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)
  USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,2229),4326);
```

Both tables have spatial indexes (but, I don't know enough about them to know if I'm supposed to be running the query using them as my target tables?)

The query I am using to get the count is this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM public.ca_la_la_areas_neighborhoods pol
JOIN poursafe.ca_licenses poi ON (ST_Within(poi.geom, pol.geom));
```

I've tried this and many other attempts and get nothing but zeros as the count or select results.

```
CREATE ca_la_la_areas_neighborhoods (
gid INTEGER,
comty_name VARCHAR (40),
cert VARCHAR (3),
shape_star VARCHAR,
shape_stle VARCHAR,
geom GEOM
);

CREATE ca_licenses (
id BIGINT,
license VARCHAR,
type VARCHAR,
master VARCHAR,
lat DOUBLE PRECISION,
lon DOUBLE PRECISION,
geom GEOM
);
```

Comment: We need sample data.

Comment: Hey Evan the sample data contains geom data that is significant in size and I likely couldn't paste here. Is there a way I can share that otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: Upload it to a paste bin, or dump it as [ekwt](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html) in the question. We only need a simplified example of something that should function and doesn't..

Comment: Here's a pastebin of some records from each table. Thanks! https://pastebin.com/u/enjoypb

Comment: You could quickly try dropping the spatial index entirely and then recreating it, seeing if that helps.

Comment: Thanks sovemp. I dropped both indexes and created new ones for each table using the code below. I'm getting the same zero response however when running the above select query: CREATE INDEX ca_licenses_gix ON poursafe.ca_licenses USING GIST (geom); and in a separate query: 
CREATE INDEX ca_la_la_areas_neighborhoods_gix ON public.ca_la_la_areas_neighborhoods USING GIST (geom);

Comment: I ended up resolving doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123243/points-in-polygon-multiple-polygons. Thanks for your help