# Points in Polygon, multiple polygons

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have this query working where I populated the prem_council column in my dst db by matching points with polygons in the src. But, I could only do it manually by stepping through each district 1-15 manually.

```
    UPDATE poursafe.ca_licenses dst
SET prem_council = '1'
FROM ca_la_la_areas_council_dist_2012 src
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM public.ca_la_la_areas_council_dist_2012 src
        WHERE ST_Within(dst.geom, src.geom )
        AND district = '1'
        );
```

I can't figure out how and wonder if you can tell me how I could automate the process so I don't have to do each district manually? The reason I ask is I have several other geographic tables and need to do a similar process. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I'm a leper. I've asked four questions since 3/28 and have gotten responses on one, but those dropped too when I was attempting a fix. Could anyone tell me what gives? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is blackbox for me without table defination and geometry type of table 
but if you try to make relation between two tables(ca_licenses and ca_la_la_areas_council_dist_2012), you can simply set district's values to prem_council ;

```
update poursafe.ca_licenses dst
    set prem_council = district 
from ca_la_la_areas_council_dist_2012 src
where st_within(dst.geom,src.geom) and dst.geom&&src.geom --to accelerate query
```

Query doesn't solve your problem , pls add table's defination and update conditions to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help Barış Serkan AKIN. That actually worked great!